# Angular and Jasmine MAT_DIALOG_DATA "TypeError: ctx.currentRoles is undefined "

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have been tasked with writing Karma/Jasmine test for components of an application our team is developing. I am not the person that wrote the actual the actual component I have run into an error that so far I have not been able to find the answer to.

This is the deleteuser.component.ts code:

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {PCplanUser} from 'src/app/models/pcplanUser';
import {PCplanRole} from 'src/app/models/pcplanRole';

import { InitService } from 'src/app/services/pcplan/initializer.service';
import { TlsApiService } from 'src/app/services/api/user-apiservice';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-deleteuser',
  templateUrl: './deleteuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deleteuser.component.scss'],
})

export class DeleteUserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {

  name :string = this.data.fullname
  confirmdelete :string = "Confirm Delete"

  currentRoles: any;

  constructor(    
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteUserComponent>,
 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
    ) { 
        console.log('data passed in is:', this.data);
      }


    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.currentRoles = this.data.role.split(',');
    }

  
    onCancelClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    ConfirmDelete() {
      
    }

   
}
```

this is the deleteuser.component.spec.ts with some code I had tried unsuccessfully in try to get a good test.

```
import { DeleteUserComponent } from './deleteuser.component';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('DeleteUserComponent', () => {
  let component: DeleteUserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeleteUserComponent>;
  let mockMatDialogRef, mockMAT_DIALOG_DATA;
  let currentRoles: any;


  /*@Component({
    selector: 'app-deleteuser',
    template: '<div></div>'
  })
  class fakeDeleteUserComponent{
    static data: string = 'Admin';
  } */ 

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockMAT_DIALOG_DATA = jasmine.createSpyObj(['role']);
    mockMAT_DIALOG_DATA.role = jasmine.createSpyObj(['split']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DeleteUserComponent, fakeDeleteUserComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: mockMatDialogRef},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: mockMAT_DIALOG_DATA},
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeleteUserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

With the test case as it currently is I am getting this error.

[image]

I tried to define currentRoles in the spec file but it wasn't working. All of the searches I have done so far have not pointed me to the answer for my error.

If you don't hear a response from me right away, it is because I will be on vacation for the rest of the week.

Comment: Eric , Did u try my answer ?

Comment: Hello Shashank, I was busy yesterday catching up from time off I had taken last week, I tried your suggestion this morning, but I am still getting the same error message: **TypeError: ctx.currentRoles is undefined in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js line 42887 > Function (line 59)**

Comment: I found out later in the day the person who is developing what I am trying to write tests for has not finished writing the feature. Maybe that is what my issue is.

Comment: I have found out some more information on the component that this question was raised about this morning.  This component is designed to only be called when a user is selected in the application.  In this case the test case I am working on is trying to create the component without providing specific user information and is checking to see if the component can be created. Since we don't really want to delete users with this test case, are there any suggestions on how to create this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the teammate who created the component and some experimentation on my own I was able to the default test of

```
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

the issue was that in the basic beforeEach statement there was a detectChanges() being called.  However this component is designed to expect user information when it is opened.

Testing passing user information is part of the integration testing that I am not yet doing.

By moving the detectChanges to any tests where I am testing the actual functionality of the component and not having it be in the beforeEach I was able to get the tests to pass.

The added benefit is have have learned something.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
  const mockDialogData= {
    role : {
      split: () => {} // or return whatever you want as a function
    }
  };
```

and then using it as :

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DeleteUserComponent, fakeDeleteUserComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: mockMatDialogRef},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: mockDialogData}, // <-- use it here
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Let me know if this worked.